# DateObject::getTimestamp() returning wrong value

Tags: 7, datetime

This is a weird issue I ran into. It seems DateObject::getTimestamp() does not return expected values, while using format('U') returns the proper timestamp.

To see the values passed, here is the code I am using:

```
  $author_date_timestamp  = $author_reminder_date_obj->format("U");
  $author_date_timestamp1 = $author_reminder_date_obj->getTimestamp();
```

kpr on these two vars:

```
$author_date_timestamp = 1345736160  // correct value

$author_date_timestamp = 1345563360  // incorrect value
```

Here is a var_dump of the author_reminder_date_obj date object:

```
class DateObject#223 (9) {
  public $granularity =>
  array(7) {
    [0] =>
    string(4) "hour"
    [1] =>
    string(6) "minute"
    [2] =>
    string(6) "second"
    [3] =>
    string(5) "month"
    [4] =>
    string(3) "day"
    [5] =>
    string(4) "year"
    [6] =>
    string(8) "timezone"
  }
  public $errors =>
  array(0) {
  }
  private $serializedTime =>
  NULL
  private $serializedTimezone =>
  NULL
  public $timeOnly =>
  bool(false)
  public $dateOnly =>
  bool(false)
  public $date =>
  string(19) "2012-08-21 11:36:00"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
```

Anyone having a clue as to why ->getTimestamp() is not behaving as I expected, I am very curious about this.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

As requested, serialized string of object:

string(151) "O:10:"DateObject":2:{s:26:"\000DateObject\000serializedTime";s:25:"2012-08-23T11:36:00-04:00";s:30:"\000DateObject\000serializedTimezone";s:16:"America/New_York";}"

Comment: I would love to know this as well.  I've recently had to modify some source data in a migration script because Migrate was converting 0000-00-00 Date formats into -0001-08-00, and I assumed the Date module was the culprit.

Comment: The difference between those two timestamps is exactly 48 hours, pretty sure that can't be a coincidence. Any chance you can dump a serialised string of the object and post it here?

Comment: @Clive indeed. I am setting back the DateObject 2 days in a function, but I clone the DateObject in the function and the object returned had proper date. Serialized object string is posted in the update above friend.

Comment: Thanks, didn't get very with that I'm afraid. The `DateObject` class doesn't override the base class's `getTimestamp()` method so what you're calling there is a raw `DateTime::getTimestamp()` method. If there's a bug I'm willing to bet it's in the date module (not in PHP). Would it be possible to post the function that clones/alters the date object?